# Unable to use wget command

Tags: wget

I am using Ubuntu 13.10 with proxy servers, which require an User ID and password.

I am unable to run the `wget` command. It returns:

```
Resolving sourceforge.net (sourceforge.net)... failed: Name or service not known.
wget: unable to resolve host address ‘sourceforge.net’
```

What can be done to resolve this?

Comment: you have eget package installed ?

# sudo apt-get install wget -y

If you have already have a check using 

# dpkg -l | grep wget

Comment: @Babinlonston - if `wget` won't work, there not much chance that `apt-get` will work *(wget should work through proxies, apt-get just stops)*

Comment: yes below my solution is there

Answer (score 1):

Edit your Resolv conf using

```
# sudo vim /etc/resolv.conf
```

Then Enter the below

```
nameserver 192.168.1.1
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 4.4.4.4
```

**Replace 192.168.1.1 with your Router IP**

Edit this file too if not your DNS will override it

```
# sudo vim /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base
```

Then Enter the below

```
nameserver 192.168.1.1
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 4.4.4.4
```

Then **Restart** your Server Using

```
# sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways of running `wget` behind a proxy. Either set the appropriate environment variables and `wget` will act according to them or configure the `wget` configuration file - `wgetrc`.

**Set the environment variable**

Before setting the environment variables, lets first see if there are any preset proxy variables present. We can get that information using the following command.

```
env | grep proxy

http_proxy=http://foo.bar:3128
no_proxy=localhost,127.0.0.1
```

If no proxy environment variable is set, it will go for direct connections. Let's take an example of my college. We use a HTTP proxy server. Running `wget` without setting the `http_proxy` environment variable just fails. So, lets set this env (environment variable). variable first

```
export http_proxy="http://foo.bar:8080"
```

Now, run `wget` and it should work like a charm. If your proxy also requires authentication i.e username and password then use this format to set the env:

```
export http_proxy="http://username:password@foo.bar:8080"
```

Similarly, for other type of proxies, set the corresponding env - `ftp_proxy`, `https_proxy` etc.

Please note that, the above commands will be in effect only till the user session expires, i.e. by running the above commands we are just setting the proxy env. for a session, not permanently. And usually we wouldn't want to run the command everytime we login. So, to make it permanent, we can either set the value in wget's configuration - `wgetrc` file or set the environment in `~/.bashrc` file.

```
echo "export http_proxy=http://foo.bar:8080/" | tee -a ~/.bashrc
```

It should be noted that, this way we might be affecting the user's proxy settings. A better way is to set the settings permanently in wget's configuration file, this way no other app. is affected.

**Configuring the `wgetrc` file**

Like most of the applications `wget` has a configuration file too - `wgetrc`:

- `/etc/wgetrc`, or
- `~/.wgetrc`.

The former is for global changes and the latter one is for local settings(user specific). We will go into the details later, lets just see how to apply the proxy settings. Its similar to setting the proxy environment variable, just exclude the export command. Open the file `~/.wgetrc` file. If one doesn't exist, then create it.

```
vim ~/.wgetrc
```

Now, add the corresponding statement in the file. Read the section "Set the environment variable" to find this.

**How to disable/turn-off the proxy settings**

Once you have configured the proxy settings in the `wgetrc` file, everytime you run `wget`, it will automatically connect to the proxy server. Sometimes for local/LAN based downloads, you may not need the proxy server. In such cases we can turn off the proxy settings using the `--no-proxy` argument in the command:

```
wget --no-proxy http://10.0.0.1/file.tgz
```

**If the proxy requries authentication - Username & Password**

We already know the format for setting the environment variable with username and password. Wget provides you two methods to mention the username and password for proxy server.

- Mention it in the command in the form of arguments.
- Set the values in the configuration file, `/etc/wgetrc` or `~/.wgetrc`

If the authentication you are using is static, then its better set it in the configuration file. If its just one time thing or if you want to overwrite the settings in configuration file then you can use the `--proxy-user` and `--proxy-password` options.

```
wget --proxy-user=username --proxy-password=password http://foo.bar/file.tgz
```

For permanent changes, its always advised to change the configuration file.

Once again, for global changes modify the `/etc/wgetrc` file otherwise go for `~/.wgetrc` file. Open any of the file and append/add the following lines in it.

```
proxy_user=username
proxy_password=password
```

[Source](http://linuxers.org/tutorial/wget-proxy-how-run-wget-behind-proxy-server)

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was avahi-deamon which was messing up the DNS responses for certain hostnames. I had to uninstall avahi and everything worked:

```
sudo apt remove avahi-daemon
```